# Gorilla WebSocket disconnects after a minute

Tags: nginx, go, websocket, gorilla

I'm using Go (Golang) 1.4.2 with Gorilla WebSockets behind an nginx 1.4.6 reverse proxy. My WebSockets are disconnecting after about a minute of having the page open. Same behavior occurs on Chrome and Firefox.

At first, I had problems connecting the server and client with WebSockets. Then, I read that I needed to tweak my nginx configuration. This is what I have.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    proxy_pass_header Server;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1234;
    }
}
```

My Go code is basically echoing back the client's message. (Errors omitted for brevity). This is my `HandleFunc`.

```
var up = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:  1024,
    WriteBufferSize: 1024,
}

ws, _ := up.Upgrade(resp, req, nil)
defer ws.Close()

var s struct {
    Foo string
    Bar string
}

for {
    ws.ReadJSON(&s)
    ws.WriteJSON(s)
}
```

The JavaScript is pretty simple as well.

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://example.com/ws/");
ws.addEventListener("message", function(evnt) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(evnt.data));
});

var s = {
    Foo: "hello",
    Bar: "world"
};
ws.send(JSON.stringify(s));
```

Go is reporting `websocket: close 1006 unexpected EOF`. I know that when I leave or refresh the page `ReadJSON` returns `EOF`, but this appears to be a different error. Also, the unexpected EOF happens by itself after about a minute of having the page open.

I have an `onerror` function in JavaScript. That event doesn't fire, but `onclose` fires instead.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I had the same issue, the problem is the nginx configuration. It defaults to a 1 minute read timeout for `proxy_pass`:

> Syntax:   proxy_read_timeout time;
>
> Default: proxy_read_timeout 60s;
>
> Context: http, server, location

See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout

In my case I've increased the timeout to 10 hours:

`proxy_read_timeout  36000s;`